# External intellisense file for javascript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I know you can use < loc > for localization, but it still seems to require the XML comments in the normal functions (ie, duplicate tags).  What I want to be able to do is write functions as I normally would, perhaps even without comments, but have the intellisense come from another file.  Something like this:

**MyScript.js**

```
function herp(a) {
    return ('merp');
}
function derp(a) {
    return ('merp');
}
```

**MyScript.intellisense.js**

```
function herp(a) {
    /// <summary>This function herps a flerp.</summary>
    /// <param name='a' type='String'>The flerp you want to herp.</param>
    /// <returns>The finished herp</returns>
}
function derp(a) {
    /// <summary>This function derps a flerp.</summary>
    /// <param name='a' type='String'>The flerp you want to derp.</param>
    /// <returns>The finished derp</returns>
}
```

Then, in my main **site.js** file I could type

```
herp(
```

and see the working intellisense.

Comment: kinda: /// <loc filename="messageFilename.xml" format="messagebundle"/> according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514138.aspx

Comment: That's for localization, as I stated in my intro.  It may be what I have to use, but it's not what I want, as it requires you to put some of the XML inline even though it is overwritten by the localized file.

Comment: you could write a dev-only shell js file that mocks the actual functions but includes xml comments. if you loaded it next your "real" js file, and blocked xml comments from the real file, and the function/object names match in both files, it just might work. you kinda have that already in your question's code...

Comment: That's basically what I'm doing, but it basically "overwrites" the one with comments.

Comment: swapping the order or using a hack like document.write("script src=... should be able to hide the legit functions from VS but not the browser during development. even an eval should be enough to trick VS. That way you get suggestions and it works when you press F5...

Comment: Swapping the order did it, duh...  Thanks.  I think this will work, if you'd like to post as an answer.

Comment: I posted my answer just to show it in 100% working order, but if you'll post your second comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: you're answer's fine, just glad you got it working and to learn a new trick...

Answer (score 0):

So basically it works as desired with the following structure:

**functions.intellisense.js**

```
function herp(a) {
    /// <summary>This function herps a flerp.</summary>
    /// <param name='a' type='String'>The flerp you want to herp.</param>
    /// <returns>The finished derp</returns>
}
function derp(a) {
    /// <summary>This function derps a flerp.</summary>
    /// <param name='a' type='String'>The flerp you want to derp.</param>
    /// <returns>The finished derp</returns>
}
```

**functions.js**

```
function herp(a) {
    return ('merp');
}
function merp(a) {
    return ('merp');
}
```

**site.js** *(intellisense works as desired in this file)*

```
/// <reference path="functions.intellisense.js" />

window.onload = function () {
    alert(herp('test'));
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    Documentation/intellisense test.
    <script src="Scripts/functions.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/site.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```